# Merging two separate data series into one Excel Chart with different X axis points

Tags: excel

I have two data sets that I want to graph, some share the same X-axis values some do not.

**Data Set 1**

```
X         Y
9:30:29   5
9:31:00   6
9:32:00   7
```

**Data Set 2**

```
X         Y
9:30:29   4
9:31:03   3
9:32:00   2
9:33:01   1
```

I want to graph Data Set 1 and Data Set2 in an area graph, so Data Set 1 and 2 will share X-axis point `9:30:29` and `9:32:00`

What I am running into is when I graph the second set, it basically overlays the Y data on the same X axis points from Data Set 1.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure you use an XY Scatter chart type (not Line).
2. Make sure you add the second series' X values as well as its Y values.